# Android: debugging if and else statement

Tags: android, android-activity

I am writing a simple Android application for a class and I'm doing a conversion program that will convert inches > feet > yards > miles.  I am having issues figuring out why if and else statements are not coming together.  I am pasting the Main.Java so you can see what I have if I need to post the main xml/strings please let me know, but everything is parsing out until i get to the if or else statements.  It says that it is looking for (), but when I add that it says that it is looking for boolean values where I have double, but I am parsing the text above it so I thought double should be fine after the parsing.  I'm trying to make this as clear as possible, but this is my first programming class beyond programming logic so my terminology likely isn't great.

```html
package unitconversion.androidbootcamp.net.unitconversion;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    double inchesPerFoot = 12;
    double feetPerYard = 3;
    double yardsPerMile = 1760;
    double txtNumberOfUnits;
    double totalUnits;
    double unitChoice;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText units =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumberOfUnits);
        final Spinner Converstion = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Units_Array);
        Button Submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Submit);
        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        final TextView result= ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Result));
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtNumberOfUnits = Integer.parseInt(units.getText().toString());
                DecimalFormat number = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
                if unitChoice = inchesPerFoot
                        totalUnits = inchesPerFoot / txtNumberOfUnits
                else
                if unitChoice = feetPerYard
                        totalUnits = feetPerYard / txtNumberOfUnits
                else
                if unitChoice = yardsPerMile;
                        totalUnits = yardsPerMile / txtNumberOfUnits;
                unitChoice = units.getSelectedItem().tostring();
                result.setText("Total Units for" + unitChoice +" is "+ number.format(totalUnits));
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your unitChoice is a string. did you want to compare the choosen unit with the text?

```
unitChoice = units.getSelectedItem().tostring(); //<--- You make unitChoice String
if (unitChoice.equals("inchesPerFoot"))
  totalUnits = inchesPerFoot / txtNumberOfUnits
else if (unitChoice.equals("feetPerYard"))
  totalUnits = feetPerYard / txtNumberOfUnits
else if (unitChoice.equals("yardsPerMile"))
  totalUnits = yardsPerMile / txtNumberOfUnits;
```

And you must set this `double unitChoice;` as String as well. And will become `String unitChoice`

Comment: I think it's actually more messed up than intended the UnitChoice should likely be Conversion.  Or am I viewing it wrong.  In the spinner it gives the 3 choices of inches > feet , feet > yards, and yards > miles.  Does that make sense by reading it?

Comment: yes.. you can change it to unitChoice.equals("inches > feet") for example

Answer (score 0):

write the if conditions like this:

```
if (unitChoice == feetPerYard)
```

you need the parens, but you also need to use a == for comparisons, the single = is an assignment operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here

```
if unitChoice = yardsPerMile;
```

U have added semicolon to the if condition, removing it will work.

```
if (unitChoice == yardsPerMile)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in your if else statement:

```
if unitChoice == inchesPerFoot
    totalUnits = inchesPerFoot / txtNumberOfUnits;
else
if unitChoice == feetPerYard
    totalUnits = feetPerYard / txtNumberOfUnits;
else
if unitChoice == yardsPerMile
    totalUnits = yardsPerMile / txtNumberOfUnits;
```

- Using single ' = ' symbols in condition of if (use double ' == ' instead)
- Using semicolon at wrong places.